# Why are the deleted products are alosy displayed under the new arrivals in magento site

Tags: magento-1.9

I have deleted some products from the site using admin panel ,but still those products appear under the new arrivals and best sellers(In the homepage).How to fix this issue?

Comment: did you reindexed and cleared cache after deleting them?

Comment: Thanks .I forgot to reindex .Thanks a lot for your support.It fix the issue

Comment: Can you please add it as a answer.Then I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do re-indexing after making any changes in product. Sometimes changes done in product may not reflect in frontend until you do reindexing.